# UWSGI Django connect http uwsgi.ini

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

Someone can tell me why this line works for me:

```
sudo uwsgi --chdir=/home/krzyzak21/venv/my_gless --module=my_gless.wsgi:application --env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_gless.settings --master  --http=127.0.0.1:8000  --home=/home/krzyzak21/venv/
```

but this:

```
sudo uwsgi --ini my_gless/config/uwsgi.ini
```

dont and add error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f49a03debc0 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

```
    [uwsgi]
    projectname =my_gless
    base = /home/krzyzak21/venv/%(projectname)
    
    master = true
    virtualenv = /home/krzyzak21/venv/%(projectname)
    pythonpath = %(base)
    chdir = %(base)
    env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(projectname).settings
    module = %(projectname).wsgi:application
```

my pythonpath

```
[
    "",
    "/usr/lib/python38.zip",
    "/usr/lib/python3.8",
    "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload",
    "/home/krzyzak21/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `home` arguments are different in the two configurations.

The working configuration is effectively

```
sudo uwsgi
 --chdir=/home/krzyzak21/venv/my_gless
 --env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_gless.settings
 --home=/home/krzyzak21/venv/
 --http=127.0.0.1:8000 
 --master 
 --module=my_gless.wsgi:application
```

and the non-working one is

```
sudo uwsgi
 --chdir=/home/krzyzak21/venv/my_gless
 --env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_gless.settings
 --master
 --module=my_gless.wsgi:application
 --pythonpath=/home/krzyzak21/venv/my_gless
 --virtualenv=/home/krzyzak21/venv/my_gless
```

– in particular, `--home` (a.k.a `--virtualenv`) seems to be incorrect, as is `--pythonpath`. It's unlikely that there'd be a `my_gless` directory within a venv.